# Compositum of unramified subextensions

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of non-archimedian henselian valued fields.
Why if $L$ is a compositum of unramified subextensions, then finitely of them suffice ?
(see [Unramified algebraic extensions of local fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792955/unramified-algebraic-extensions-of-local-fields)).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by "finitely of them suffice"?

Comment: @Mathmo123 I mean that if $L$ is the compositum of the family $(L_i)_{i \in I}$, then there exists a finite subset $J$ of $I$ such that $L$ is the compositum of the finite subfamily $(L_j)_{j \in J}$.

Comment: A finite *separable* extension of fields $L/K$ has only finitely many intermediate fields, so $L$ could not be a compositum of infinitely manny different field extensions of $K$.

Comment: Without separability : when adding the $L_i$ one by one to the compositum you get an increasing tower of fields, that $[L:K]<\infty$ means this tower ends being constant.